# express/Node testing calls to mysql from local vs docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I am trying to make day-to-day development easier  by being able to run my code on my local directly and then deploying to a container and then testing it via  container. I am using a simple Express/NodeJS  application that connects  to a local mysql instance using both a local run directly using node and docker  run via container

## Local

When I create this config  to connect to MYSQL via my local I am able  to connect just fine (using  `localhost` as a host)

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'user-password'
});
```

Using `node server.js`

## Local using Docker

When I create this config  to connect to MYSQL via my local I am able  to connect just fine (`my-db` is the mysql service name in my *docker-compose.yml* since i cannot use `localhost`.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'my-db',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'user-password'
});
```

Using `docker-compose run <myimage>`

## The Problem

I have to constantly keep  changing my connection code  to switch between localhost and my-db when running locally against *node server* vs running via *docker-compose run* . Is there a way I can make the `connection` agnostic of how I am running  the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use for an environment variable.  A setup I find works well is to make host names like this configurable via environment variables, falling back to defaults that will make sense for developers who may not have them set.

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT || 3306,
    ...
});
```

If you just `npm run start` your application without setting those environment variables, you'll get those defaults.  But in a Docker setup, it's easy to specify them; for example in Compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8
  application:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=database
```

This setup also helps you out if you're going to deploy to a production environment where your database is running on a separate host with its own backup strategy, or a cloud-hosted database like Amazon RDS; you can just set `$MYSQL_HOST` to point at the database host name, without changing your code.

Comment: Ah thats simple elegant and scalable environment wise. Love  it!! Thanks!